# Herokuから確認メールを送信することができない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sendmail

RailsからSendgridでメールを送信しようとしているのですが、正しく送信されません。次のエラーが原因でしょうか？

```
sh: 1: /usr/sbin/sendmail: not found
```

config/environments/prduction.rb

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => '###'}
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address => 'smtp.mandrillapp.com',
  :port => 25,
  :authentication => "login",
  :user_name => '###',
  :password => '###',
  :domain => '###',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SendGridを使うのであれば、まず使用中のHerokuインスタンスにSendGridアドオンが追加されていることを確認して下さい。

それから smtp_settings のなかに mandrillapp の文字が見えます。MandrillはSendGridとは別のメール送信サービスです。
SendGridのヘルプページを見て正しい設定を入力して下さい。

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sendgrid#ruby-rails

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  :port           => '587',
  :authentication => :plain,
  :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
  :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
  :domain         => 'heroku.com',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

もしアドオンを使わずにSendGridを外部サービスとして使うのであれば以下のような設定になるかもしれません。（僕は試したことがないですが）

https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Frameworks/rubyonrails.html

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :user_name => 'your_sendgrid_username',
  :password => 'your_sendgrid_password',
  :domain => 'yourdomain.com',
  :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  :port => 587,
  :authentication => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```